# Issue writing to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having an issue with a project I am working on dealing with SQL, i have a function that is taking a CSV file and reading it to insert it into a MySQL database.

```
function databaseWrite($filename)
        {
            $tableName = "";
            $tableName = substr($filename, 0, -3);
            echo $tableName;
            $fp = fopen( $filename ,"r");
            while ($line = fgets ($fp))
            {
                $arr =  explode(",", $line);
                $query = "INSERT INTO `".$tableName."` (Field1, Field2) VALUES (" . $arr[0] . "," . $arr[1] . ")";
                //Use the mysql api to send those queries to the database
                SQLQuery($query, $tableName);
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
```

it calls a SQL query function that actually does the query

```
function SQLQuery($query, $tableName)
        {
            global $con;
            //first run a query to create the table name if it does not exist
            mysqli_query($con,$query);
            mysqli_close($con);
        }
```

the problem is i am getting an error
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

I know my $con variable is correct because my dbconnect.php file works fine in my login function.

I have asked around and looked over the Internet and have not found a solution anywhere.

Comment: you need to pass $con to your function

Comment: Or else read about the `global` keyword here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: insert inside a loop is probably a bad idea here, you can insert multiple rows in a single query

Comment: Also learn about SQL injection protection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @BillKarwin someone with you experience should know how bad global is (in almost every case)

Comment: oops looks like i took the global out when i copied the code over, global is stated in the function, the loop goes through multiple lines, there could be hundreds and hundreds of rows.

Comment: you close the connection after every query, do you open it also? And dont do that massive overhead when using a loop. also php has csv functions you should use tahter than rolling your own

Comment: SQL Injection is not a major concern right now, this will all be done automatically, simply a file name "filename.csv" is given and it is hard coded into the program.

Comment: i thought that is what the mysqli_query does, what csv functions are there? i could not find any so i found what i am using here earlier.

Comment: no it uses the $con connection, but then you close the connection. fgetcsv() etc

Comment: @Chandler, I don't care about the filename, but what's *in* the file that breaks your SQL syntax. Not necessarily maliciously—just SQL syntax errors if the content contains `'` or other characters.

Comment: @nogad, of course `global` leads to spaghetti code, but one should be aware of rules of variable scope

Comment: @nogad it only closes the file that is being read, not the connection, or at least it should

Comment: @BillKarwin as far as I know there is nothing in the file that could cause SQL syntax errors, if there is I will get there when it comes to it.

Comment: `mysqli_close($con);` not  `fclose($fp);`

Comment: remove mysqli_close($con); from function. your code will process only first line of file, then your SQLQuery function destroys mysqli session, and all another file lines wil be processed with closed mysqli connection

Comment: @diavolicI I put that after the last function call, of course it was doing the same error before i put that inside the function, here is the current error.

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in, this is at mysqli_query($con,$query);

Comment: so $con is not what you think it is, debug that

Comment: @nogad but $con works fine with my login function.